# Como retornar um JSON em ASP.NET API que possui outro JSON dentro?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Não sei se minha pergunta expressa bem, mas o tipo de retorno que preciso é algo como isso:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "string",
    "Image": "string",
    "Why": "string",
    "What": "string",
    "WhatWillWeDo": "string",
    "ProjStatus": 0,
    "Course": {
      "CourseId": 0,
      "Name": "string"
    },
    "CourseId": 0
  }
]
```

porém, em retorno obtenho apenas:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "image": "string",
    "why": "string",
    "what": "string",
    "whatWillWeDo": "string",
    "projStatus": 0,
    "course": null,
    "courseId": 0
  }
]
```

método `GET` no `Controller`

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Project>> Get()
{
    try
    {
        var projects = 
            (from project in _acess.GetProjects()
                select project)
        .ToList();
        return projects;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

classe que é chamada no `Controller`

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
{
    // var aux = context
    //  .Projects
    //  .ToList()
    //  .Count;
    return context.Project.ToList();
}
```

a classe de projetos

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Why { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }
    public string WhatWillWeDo { get; set; }
    public ProjectStatus ProjStatus { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public enum ProjectStatus
    {
        development = 0,
        publicated = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso esteja usando `EntityFramework`, propriedades que também estão sendo mapeadas dentro da entidade precisam ser *incluidas* na consulta, tente algo como:

```
context.Project.Where(i => i.CourseId == id).Include("Course").FirstOrDefault();
```

ou

```
context.Project.Where(i => i.CourseId == id).Include(x => x.Course).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui usar o código e retornou o JSON da maneira que eu esperava. Porém, quando eu tento utilizar junto com este código context.Project.Include("Course").Find(id) não funciona, nem se eu utilizar context.Project.Where(i => i.Id== id).Include("Course") desta maneira. Teria alguma dica?

Comment: @Tester qual é a mensagem de erro? Por quê não funciona?

Comment: Eu estava colocando o método incorretamente sem perceber, está funcionando sim. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Tester Maravilha, não se esqueça de marcar como respondida :D

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas onde marco como respondida? Estou procurando pelo site e não encontro opção.

Comment: @Tester No canto superior esquerdo da minha resposta deve ter um check